# Recursive neural networks for Part-of-speech tagging?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language

So, I've been reading quite a bit about neural networks lately and from what I've read it seems that the recurrent neural networks are one of the most common once in the field of NLP.

However, the recursive neural network model is also meantioned to be very effective in the same field.

What I've seen is that studies have conducted research about Part-of-speech with reccurent neural networks and syntactical analysis such as parse trees with the recursive model.

How come? Is it possible to do as the title suggests? Since I'm not an expert in the area I would like to know what the applications of the different models are and what fundamentally makes them different from each other.